# VBO texturing does not work

Tags: opengl, textures, vbo

The problem is that this code display nothing. I have problem with my loads  of textures. If I comment the code lines about the textures treatments it works perfectly. It displays a 4 colored square. Can you help me ?

```
#define OFFSET_BUFFER(bytes) ((GLfloat *)NULL + bytes)

GLfloat vertices[12] =
{
    -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,
    -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,
};

GLfloat colors[12] =
{
    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
};

GLfloat texture[8] =
{
    0.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_WM_SetCaption("Texture Mapping",NULL);
    SDL_SetVideoMode(500, 500, 32, SDL_OPENGL);

    bool continuer = true;
    SDL_Event event;
    GLuint  buf[2];
    GLuint texture1;

    glClearDepth(1.0f);
    glClearColor(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(70.0f, (float)500.0f / (float)500.0f, 1.0f, 3000.0f);
    glewInit();

    texture1 = loadTexture("caisse.jpg");
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1);

    glGenBuffers(2, &buf[0]);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buf[0]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buf[1]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(colors), colors, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, texture1);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(texture), texture, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    while (continuer)
    {
        SDL_WaitEvent(&event);
        switch(event.type)
        {
            case SDL_QUIT:
                continuer = false;
        }

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();

        gluLookAt(0.0f, 0.0f, 3.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buf[0]);
        glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, OFFSET_BUFFER(0));

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buf[1]);
        glColorPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, OFFSET_BUFFER(0));

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, texture1);
        glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, OFFSET_BUFFER(0));

        glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
        glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

        glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4);

        glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);   
        glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
        glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);


        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        glFlush();
        SDL_GL_SwapBuffers();
    }

    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you need to start putting `glGetError()` in your code for debugging, as you're certainly generating some errors here.

You're binding your texture `texture1` with glBindBuffer, which is not correct to do so. Texture coordinates are not the same as textures. You should be generating 3 buffers instead of 2, and loading the `texture[8]` texcoords into the third buffer.

Comment: @user1364743 Please consider marking the answer as accepted by clicking the checkbox if it has solved your problem.